# Redeploy Streams on SCDF startup/restart

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have started spring cloud dataflow server in a Linux machine. I have added few stream applications and deployed it which are working fine. But when the Linux machine is rebooted, I have to manually restart SCDF and redeploy the streams.
Through Linux scripts I can start SCDF during Linux server boot up. But I couldn't find how to redeploy the streams on SCDF startup. The problem that I am addressing is the down time involved with manual intervention to redeploy the streams.

Answer (score 1):

We do not support the high availability of stream application on the local version of Spring Cloud Data Flow.  For stream deployments, the local server is for development purposes only.  This was our reasoning for moving from Spring XD (where we did provide a local runtime to keep applications running) to Spring Cloud Data Flow where we rely on a platform runtime, such as Cloud Foundry or Kubernetes to manage the application and make sure they are resilient in the case of various failures.  I notice though, we don't make this quite clear in the reference docs, so will add a section relating to that.

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

if we know the stream name as a work around we can use REST API to deploy the stream

curl -X POST  http://ip:port/streams/deployments/{streamName}